# How to reuse an instantiated module in verilog with updated inputs

Tags: verilog

I have a module :

```
module abc(
  input  in1,
  input  in2,
  output in3
);
```

Instantiating this module in another main module:

```
abc name_abc(in1, in2, out);
```

Now in1 is changed based on some other signal. From what I understand, the instantiation would have created a block of the logic, now I want to use the block already created but with different inputs or updated inputs. Is there a way to do this in verilog?

What I want to do is :

```
abc name_abc(in1_updated, in2, out);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inputs are continuous time signals. The module instantiation is not a method call but constantly executing logic, therefore any change in `in1` value will be passed directly to instance `name_abc`.

If you mean to use the same module (hardware) but being able to switch between 2 data streams, imply a mux in front of it.

```
wire   connect_to_abc_in;
assign connect_to_abc_in = (select) ? in1 : in1_alternative ;
```

Comment: @Preets if you have already learnt to program the shift to HDLs (Verilog/VHDL) can be pretty jarring, syntax can be familiar but meaning and implication is very different. Persevere and try to enjoy learning new skills.

Comment: Here is the complete code for the answer on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/33). However, I'm not sure why Icarus Verilog is giving a `implicit definition of wire logic` warning. I don't see a warning with VCS.

Comment: @VictorLyuboslavsky, you've got a typo error in `connet_to_abc_in`.